# Receiving "The requested operation requires elevation" when trying to create/set outlook object either via early/late binding in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am receiving an error which says *The requested operation requires elevation* when I am trying to create an outlook object either by early binding or late binding method with below statements

```
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
```

or

```
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

It only works when I open this Excel file with "Run as Admin" mode and run my macro. Can you help me to resolve this issue? I do not want to run my Excel with "Run as Admin..." mode to execute my code. 
I am using MS-Office professional 2013 and I am also part of the administrative group on my machine.

Comment: Is Outlook.exe configured to run as admin?

Comment: Yes, still getting same error. (Ran/Open outlook with "Run as admin..." then ran above VBA code)

Comment: No, the question was *whether* Outlook.exe was configured to run as admin.. which would explain the elevation requirement if Excel isn't running as admin.

Comment: Yes, looks like my outlook has configured to "Run as admin" , since it shows the UAC prompt when I launch/open my outlook.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason for this that I can think of, is that you somehow have OUTLOOK.EXE itself configured to *run as administrator*.

Unless you remove that configuration, the only way to instantiate an `Outlook` application is through an elevated process, since a non-admin process can't spawn an admin process.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. Let me work with my IT team to resolve this outlook issue and run it into normal mode. Will get back to you if I will face any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Close all instances of Excel, and possibly reboot your computer.

Or in my case, I was able to use SysInternals Process Explorer to kill all instances of Excel and Access (I use VBA in both, with references between the two).

In Windows 10, I find I cannot do some things in VBA if my Excel or Access are started with normal user rights. I found a search result somewhere (which I now cannot find) that recommended starting them with administrative rights. I did so, and it resolved the error. Since then I created shortcuts to always start them with admin rights.

However, the bookkeeping software we use exports to Excel, and it sometimes creates new instances. So when I look in Process Explorer, I find multiple root-instances of Excel, some with administrator rights and owned by Explorer.exe, and others with user rights and owned by the bookkeeping program or some other Windows automation process.

With Windows Task Manager, it doesn't always show all instances. So without it, if closing Excel doesn't fix the problem, it means there's a hidden instance still running, and the only way to fix it is to reboot (or install Process Explorer and use that).